# Why apt-get can't find github-ee package on a Ubuntu 18.04 release?

Tags: github, ubuntu-18.04

```
# apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
Hit:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Hit:5 https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:6 https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Fetched 247 kB in 2s (111 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done

# apt-cache search gitlab-ee
```

Search didn't find anything like gitlab-ee. However if I post the link https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee/ubuntu/ to the browser, I can find the gitlab-ee package for ubuntu/bionic.

Comment: You may not have a repository configured that contains `github-ee`. Also, you seem to be searching for `github-ee` instead of `gitlab-ee`?

Comment: thanks @PAckerman, the github-ee was just typo. I fixed it in my post. The problem stands.  From the result of "apt-get update", you can find the gitlab repository was searched.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out my Ubuntu was 18.04 but 32bit version. It was upgraded from previous Ubuntu version. gitlab-ee does not support 32bit version anymore.

After updating to 18.04.01 server 64bit, gitlab-ce was installed without issues.

The installing process does not provide sufficient messages for installer to diagnose such issues. Believe me, I am not the only one running into such clueless issue. Actually I followed other people's similar cases which I found by googling.